# How to add a new directory to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on ROS hydro ,Ubuntu 12.04.

I've created a new directory and i'm unable to add it to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  Here's what i'm writing to do this:

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH= /home/user/<name_of-directory_i_want_to_add>:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

(All in one line)

where /opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks is what i get when i type: echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

How do i add my directory to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214641/how-to-add-a-new-directory-to-ros_package_path?/) by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2015-07-27**:
Did you append this command to your `~/.bashrc` file? That's one way to make sure that you actually set it every time you open up another terminal.

**Comment by [ju78iklo9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32592/ju78iklo9/) on 2017-12-03**:
Each time I get to the "Building Your Package" I have a sum total of 2 terminals I've used:

1. Roscore
2. Everything else in lessons up to and including 1.2 Building Your Package

Two terminals

- - 

**PS I'm using ROS Kinetic NOT Hydro **
I don't know how "Hydro" got into my original query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two things: If  /opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks is already in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, you don't need to put it in your export line. This command overwrites the variable, and by putting `:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` at the end of your path, you're say add everything that is already in the variable.

Second, I don't know if it matters, but I would try exactly what you have but without the space between the equals sign and the beginning of your path, like this: `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/<name_of-directory_i_want_to_add>:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`

Edit: Also, like the comment the other fella made, if you're just typing this into the command prompt, this is only going to be effective for your current terminal. By adding it to your bashrc file, it will take effect on any new terminals in the future.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4